# assigning to 'NSBlockOperation *__strong' from incompatible type 'void (^)(void)' getNewMessages = ^{ ^ ~~

Tags: ios, exception

```
__block HAAppDelegate *appDelegate = self;
getNewMessages = ^{
    if ([FBSession.activeSession isOpen]) {
        HANetworkRequest *request = [[HANetworkRequest alloc] initWithDelegate:appDelegate];
        [request doRequest:@"getNotifications"];
    }
};


assigning to 'NSBlockOperation *__strong' from incompatible type 'void (^)(void)'
    getNewMessages = ^{
                   ^ ~~
```

Comment: You should at least add a declaration of getNewMessages since now it is not really clear what type it is.

Answer (score 1):

According to compile error `getNewMessages` is an `NSBlockOperation` object, not ObjectiveC's block. So you should use it following way:

```
getNewMessages = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    if ([FBSession.activeSession isOpen]) {
        HANetworkRequest *request = [[HANetworkRequest alloc] initWithDelegate:appDelegate];
        [request doRequest:@"getNotifications"];
    }];
```

Comment: is this code will work, i dont want to break my functionality in any case as my app is live and thousands of users using it.  Also this error comes with 8.3 sdk only.

Comment: @AlirazaPucit This looks like *the* answer to me (you should consider upvoting people who help you).  The new error is more likely to do with the new compiler which spots more errors than the previous version.